# How do i install apt-get on Redhat AWS linux machine

Tags: amazon-s3, apt-get

I have spun a Redhat linux machine in aws,but struggling to install apt-get ,here is uname -a

Linux ip-172-31-69-100.ec2.internal 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 20:48:51 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Could you provide help just to let me know how to get apt-get working in Redhat linux aws machine

Comment: just use `yum` instead

Comment: didnt worked `[root@ip-172-31-69-100 ec2-user]# sudo yum install apt-get
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package apt-get available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@ip-172-31-69-100 ec2-user]#`

Comment: I mean dont use apt-get at all and use yum to do what you need

Comment: Extending on Mostafa's response, `apt-get` is Debian's package manager, Red Hat uses `yum` its not easy to make `apt-get` work on a Red Hat machine, and its redundant since `yum` is already there. Is there a specific reason for your need of `apt-get`?

Comment: all i require is to run `sudo apt-get install ntp ntpdate ntpstat` ,basically i want to my ec2 unix machine to have clock which will be synchronised with upstream network server

Answer (score 0):

actually my search was how to make sudo snap conjure-up --classic working in Amazon aws Linux machine,I was trying to run

sudo snap conjure-up --classic working in Amazon  aws Linux machine,but i was getting message as snap not found sometimes apt-get not found,my quest was then how do i get snap in amazon linux machine?

Resolution:-one of my colleague explained"Unfortunately, conjure-up has been developed by Canonical, the creator of Ubuntu and is only tested on Ubuntu Linux machines. It most likely won't work on other OS'es. You'll need to spin up an Ubuntu machine to use conjure-up."

[image]